# GraphQL format return objects instead of arrays

Tags: arrays, object, graphql

I would like to have GraphQl to return my results in a different format. Instead of arrays like below ...

```
[
    {
        id: 19234,
        license: "value1"
    },
    {
        id: 25479,
        license: "value2"
    }
]
```

I would preferably have objects with the ID being the object's name

```
[
    "19234": {
        license: "value1"
    },
    "25479": {
        license: "value2"
    }
]
```

Is this possible and if it is how do I go about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using this query:

```
query {
  items @key(fields: "id") {
    key: id
    license
  }
}
```

This query will return an object where each item's id field is used as the key of the object, and the value is an object containing the license field. Note that the GraphQL response will still be in JSON format, and the keys in a JSON object must be strings.

To implement this query in C#, you would need to use a GraphQL client library that supports aliases and the @key directive.

An example using the HotChocolate GraphQL client library:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HotChocolate;
using HotChocolate.Execution;

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string License { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Data { get; set; }
}

var request = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = @"
      query {
        items @key(fields: ""id"") {
          key: id @alias(name: ""key"")
          license
        }
      }
    "
};

var response = await new HttpClient()
    .SendJsonAsync<GraphQLResponse<Response>>(HttpMethod.Post, "https://my-graphql-api.com/graphql", request);

Dictionary<string, Item> items = response.Data.Data;
```

So the actual response will look like this:

```
 {
      "19234": {
        "license": "value1"
      },
      "25479": {
        "license": "value2"
      }
    }
```